# Compiling OpenSSL 3.0.0 on Win x64 - how to specify FIPS in config

Tags: openssl

I am able to successfully compile openssl 3.0.0 using VS 2022 on Win x64 environment.
However, I am not able to find where does the configuration to do a FIPS compliant compilation needs to be specified.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805955/how-do-i-compile-fips-capable-openssl-on-windows-x64) is helpful, but is outdated. The method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861980/completing-the-installation-of-the-openssl-3-0-2-fips-module) is not applicable any more since the manual specifies that the openssl fipsinstall does not work for openssl3.0.0 alpha release 16 onwards ([here])[3](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Completing_the_installation_of_the_FIPS_Module)

I need some guidance on how to specify FIPS capability to the configuration file for compiling this on Win 64 using VS.

Thanks for your attention and time